# HTTP Error 500 on phpinfo.php

Tags: php, mysql, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

I just installed MySQL on Windows Server 2008 R2.
I followed the instructions on: [Install and Configure MySQL for PHP Applications on IIS7][1]

And when i was gonna check phpinfo.php, i get error 500. Here is a ScreenShot that i took when using RDP to our Windows 2008 R2 server. https://i.stack.imgur.com/hW7qG.png

I have no idea what causes this error. And i have absolutley no idea how to fix this.
Here is the error log that IIS made for today: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=11719906829973224437
i've searched around using google, and there was no solution for my problem.

I have PHP Manager, and it does not show any message that would indicate there is a problem with the PHP configuration.

Any idea how i can fix this, so that i can continue on developing the website for my company?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Windows Server, but normally the first place to look would be the error log. As recommended by the error message...

Comment: Did you do anything to make IIS7 support not just mysql, but php? There are a few things you have to do. iis7 out of the box will not natively support php without a little work. http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php

Comment: @Tim Yes, before i started with MySQL i configured IIS7 to support php, i even installed PHP Manager.

jeroen i've checked the error logs, but they do not tell me anything spesific about what is causing the problem.

Comment: I figured out what was causing the error. I needed to Install MS Visual C+ on my server both x86 and x64.

Comment: Since you figured out the answer, you should post it below and accept it. The PHP download page does indicate VC++ dependencies.